# Cannot access DNS from external network

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, centos-6

I have setup a MaraDNS instance on CentOS 6.5. I can access the DNS records from local machine—on which MaraDNS is installed—by doing `nslookup` but cannot access the DNS server records from Internet on other machines.

When I do nslookup from other machine via internet, I get:

> connection timed out; no servers could be reached

I have setup iptables as:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: As a sanity check, please tell us the `nslookup` command you are using. Can you connect to your server from the "Internet" (non-local) machine by other means? What happens if you ACCEPT tcp/53?

Comment: @G-Man- Below solution worked. Thanks bdw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `bind_address` in your `/etc/marac` file [as explained here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dns.maradns):

> If you want to tie the process to a specific interface, edit the
>   `bind_address` parameter. This defaults to 0.0.0.0 meaning any
>   interface. If both recursive and authoritative DNS is needed (i.e. you
>   add a zonefile) you have to change this to the specific IP addresse(s)
>   where you need maradns to listen, otherwise it will refuse to start.

So if your `bind_address` is set to `127.0.0.1` then that would strictly bind it to localhost connections. So if you want the interface to be networked outside of localhost connections, set it to `0.0.0.0`.

I don’t use MaraDNS so I’m not 100% sure on the naming of the `bind_address` parameter, [but more info here](http://maradns.samiam.org/tutorial/man.mararc.html) points to the param being named `ipv4_bind_addresses`:

> **ipv4_bind_addresses:** The IP addresses to give the MaraDNS server. This
>   accepts one or more ipv4 IPs in dotted-decimal (e.g. "127.0.0.1")
>   notation, and specifies what IP addresses the MaraDNS server will
>   listen on. Multiple bind addresses are separated with a comma, like
>   this: "10.1.2.3, 10.1.2.4, 127.0.0.1"

Comment: That helps. I have to add my server's IP address to the `bind_address`. 0.0.0.0 does not work but after adding my public IP it works! Thanks